# $G$ satisfying $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group in which, for some integer $n>1$, $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$ for all $a,b\in G$.

Show that

- $G^{(n)}=\{x^n|x\in G\}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.
- $G^{(n-1)}=\{x^{n-1}|x\in G\}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.
- $a^{n-1}b^n=b^na^{n-1}$ for all $a,b\in G$.
- $\left( aba^{-1}b^{-1}\right)^{n(n-1)}=e$ for all $a,b\in G$.

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: As a hint for the first one: for any group $G$ $\{x^n|x\in G\}$ is closed under conjugation, now just try to show that it is actually a subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

Partial anwer (first point):

Define $\phi:G\rightarrow G$ by $x\mapsto x^{n}$.

Then $\phi\left(xy\right)=\left(xy\right)^{n}=x^{n}y^{n}=\phi\left(x\right)\phi\left(y\right)$
so it is a grouphomomorphism.

Then $G^{\left(n\right)}=\text{im }\phi$
is a subgroup.

If $y\in G^{\left(n\right)}$ then $y=x^{n}$ for some
$x$ and for every $g\in G$ we find $gyg^{-1}=gx^{n}g^{-1}=\left(gxg^{-1}\right)^{n}\in G^{\left(n\right)}$.

This proves that subgroup $G^{\left(n\right)}$ is normal.

Comment: I have got the proof of te second part. That follows from using $\left(gxg^{-1}\right)^{-1}=gx^{-1}g^{-1}$.